# Cache eviction on hashes on Redis

Tags: redis

If I have several hashes on Redis, each with keys that expire in 24 hours, if memory runs out while using an eviction policy like allkeys-lru, will Redis remove an entire hash or single keys?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Redis only supports expiration at the key's level. Therefore, once set with a TTL, your key that contains a hashmap will be expired entirely (all child fields will be gone with it). The same goes for the other Redis data types (e.g. Sets and Lists).

If you use Hashes for storing key names that need to expire, simply set the TTL for each such key name individually instead of for the Hash's key.

Comment: Just to confirm: when you say `Redis only supports expiration at the key's level.` you do not refer to the keys contained in Redis hash keys (level 1), but to Redis keys in general (level 0)?

Comment: Exactly. Think of the "keys" inside a level 0 Hash key as "fields" and then expiration of keys makes sense (but not of fields :)).